# How to display details from an object to a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, object, oop

I am making a program which will test if an airplane is allowed to fly or not. It's my very first personal project using Windows Form and C#. I made a lot of progress, however, I am having a huge problem with a feature I want to have. I have two forms called `Main` & `FlightSetup` and the second form uses a class called `AircraftClass` which contains constructors, behaviours, and properties.

[image: form]

---

**PROBLEM**

I will try to make it simple and understandable. I am calling class `AircraftClass`  inside `public void addaircraftButton_Click` to make an object and store all necessary details like `aircraftModel`,`airlineName`, etc. However, I have a ListBox called `aircraftList` which shows only the aircraft name. The idea is to display all that data/details depending on what the user selects from the `aircraftList` inside a TextBox called `detailsList` (yes, I called it like that, but it's a textbox). This is when the issue happens, it is not displaying the correct information, and it's showing the properties value for `AircraftClass`

---

**NOTES**

`aircraftList` & `detailsList` are inside `Main` Form - I do know that there are some obvious mistakes here, but I am still learning, please go easy on me :(

Variables Inside `Main` Form

```
        int planeCount = 0; int tailNumber = 0; int planeIndex;
        string planeModel = "NONE"; string airline = "NONE";
        double distanceM = 0.0; double fuelG = 0.0; double maxKG = 0.0; double totalKG = 0.0;
        int passengers= 0; int bag1=0; int bag2 = 0;
```

---

Main Code (Only `addbuttom` method)

```
        public void addaircraftButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FlightSetup addAircraft = new FlightSetup(); //CREATES INFO INSIDE DETAILS

            string nl = "\r\n";

            using (addAircraft)
            {
                DialogResult result = addAircraft.ShowDialog();

                planeModel = addAircraft.planeModel_textbox.Text;
                airline = addAircraft.airline_textbox.Text;

                tailNumber = int.Parse(addAircraft.tailno_textbox.Text);
                passengers= int.Parse(addAircraft.passengerTextBox.Text);
                bag1 = int.Parse(addAircraft.carryonTextBox.Text);
                bag2= int.Parse(addAircraft.checkedBagsTextBox.Text);

                distanceM = double.Parse(addAircraft.distance_textbox.Text);
                fuelG = double.Parse(addAircraft.fuel_textbox.Text);
                maxKG = double.Parse(addAircraft.maxweight_textbox.Text);

                AircraftDetails test = new AircraftDetails(planeModel,airline,tailNumber,passengers,bag1,bag2,distanceM,fuelG,maxKG,totalKG);
                test.AircraftModel = addAircraft.planeModel_textbox.Text;
                MessageBox.Show("Flight Setup is COMPLETED! \n\nPerfom Unit Testing For Take-Off Permission", "FLIGHT SAVED!");

                planeCount++;
                noaircraft_label.Text = planeCount.ToString();
                aircraftList.Items.Add(planeModel + " - REGULAR ROLE");
            }

        }
```

---

Main Code (Only `aircraftList` method)

```
  public void aircraftList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //PENDING SOLUTION
        {
            AircraftDetails getData = new AircraftDetails();
            StringBuilder insertData = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);
            string nl = "\r\n";

            planeIndex = aircraftList.SelectedIndex;

            if (planeIndex > -1)
            {
                insertData.Append(getData.AircraftModel.ToString());
                insertData.Append(nl);

                detailsList.Text = insertData.ToString();
            }
        }
```

---

AircraftClass Code

```
{
    public class AircraftDetails
    {
        string aircraftModel = "UNKNOWN";
        string airlineName = "UNKNOWN";

        int id = 0; //not in use

        int tailNumber = 0;
        int passengerNo = 0;
        int carrybag = 0;
        int checkbag = 0;
        double distance = 0.0;
        double fuel = 0.0;
        double mWeight = 0.0;
        double totalWeight = 0.0;

        int errorCount = 0;
        
        //Constructors
        public AircraftDetails()
        {
            aircraftModel = "UNKNOWN";
            airlineName = "UNKNOWN";
            id = 0;
            tailNumber = 0;
            passengerNo = 0;
            carrybag = 0;
            checkbag = 0;
            distance = 0.0;
            fuel = 0.0;
            mWeight = 0.0;
            totalWeight = 0.0;
        }
        public AircraftDetails(string aircraftModel, string airlineName, int tailNumber, int passengerNo, int carrybag, int checkbag, double distance, double fuel, double mWeight, double totalWeight)
        {
            this.aircraftModel = aircraftModel;
            this.airlineName = airlineName;
            this.tailNumber = tailNumber;
            this.passengerNo = passengerNo;
            this.carrybag = carrybag;
            this.checkbag = checkbag;
            this.distance = distance;
            this.fuel = fuel;
            this.mWeight = mWeight;
            this.totalWeight = totalWeight;
        }

        //BEHAVIOUR
        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (this.passengerNo >= 1)
            return "Aircraft: " + aircraftModel + "\r\n Tail Number:" + tailNumber + "\r\nOperator: " + airlineName + "\r\nAircraft: " + "\r\nFlight Distance: " + distance + "\r\nFuel: " + fuel +
                "\r\nMax Weight Allowed: " + mWeight + "\r\nTotal Weight: " + totalWeight + "\r\nPassengers: "+passengerNo+ "\r\nCarry-On Bags: "+carrybag+ "\r\nChecked Bags: "+checkbag;
            else
            {
                errorCount++;
                return "Passengers were less than 0\r\nIt means error was recorded\r\nError Count: "+errorCount;
            }
        }

        //Properties
        public string AircraftModel
        {
            get { return aircraftModel; }
            set { aircraftModel = value; }
        }
        public string Airline
        {
            get { return airlineName; }
            set { airlineName = value; }
        }
        public int TailNumber
        {
            get { return tailNumber; }
            set { tailNumber = value; }
        }
        public int PassengerNo
        {
            get { return passengerNo; }
            set { passengerNo = value; }
        }
        public int OnBoardBags
        {
            get { return carrybag; }
            set { carrybag = value; }
        }
        public int CheckedBags
        {
            get { return checkbag; }
            set { checkbag = value; }
        }
        public double FlightDistance
        {
            get { return distance; }
            set { distance = value; }
        }
        public double Fuel
        {
            get { return fuel; }
            set { fuel = value; }
        }
        public double MaxWeight
        {
            get { return mWeight; }
            set { mWeight = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your main problems are here: `aircraftList.Items.Add(planeModel + " - REGULAR ROLE");` and here: `AircraftDetails getData = new AircraftDetails(); // [...] insertData.Append(getData.AircraftModel.ToString());`. You have probably tagged the questions correctly, adding `oop`. This is not how you handle objects in this platform. Also, you clearly understand that you're creating an empty `AircraftDetails` object and suppose to extract values from it -- You need a `BindingList<AircraftDetails>`, set it as the DataSource of the ListBox. After that, any SelectedItem is a `AircraftDetails` object

Comment: You cast the current SelectedItem to `AircraftDetails` to get the selected object, call its `.ToString()` method to show the details you have set in the override -- You can add objects to the BindingList, which is going to automatically update the content of the ListBox. The only thing that remains is to set the `DisplayMember` Property of the ListBox to a property of `AircraftDetails`, probably `AircraftModel`, and you're done -- In other words, explore how data bindings work. What you have here is a simple implementation, should get you started

Comment: Hey @Jimi, Pardon me the question, but could you provided me a code example or a video that could help me out doing what I am doing, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is **how to display details from an object to a TextBox**.

I see in your code that you've done a good job of overriding the `ToString` method. In a sense, you answered your own question because that's what it takes!

But let's try and boil all that code into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that will include data binding as Jimi so rightly recommended. The bare bones of our bindable class has this override:

```
// Minimal example of a class
class AircraftDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        List<string> builder = new List<string>();
        builder.Add($"{Airline} {Flight}");
        builder.Add($"FlightStatus: {FlightStatus}");
        builder.Add($"{OnboardBags} bags onboard");
        builder.Add($"{CheckedBags} bags checked");
        builder.Add($"Total bags: {TotalBags}");
        builder.Add($"Fuel onboard: {Fuel.ToString("F2")}");
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, builder);
    }
    .
    .
    .
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

Next, write the main form code to display details from an object to a TextBox.

[image: show from button]

One salient point is that `ToString()` can just be called on `object` because it's [virtual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual).

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonShowObjectInTextbox.Click += onButtonShowObjectInTextbox;
    }
    private void onButtonShowObjectInTextbox(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // For demonstration purposes, make an object.
        // (Make sure parameterless constructor `AircraftDetails(){ }` is present)
        object o = new AircraftDetails
        {
            Flight = "UA2907",
            Airline = Airline.United,
            Fuel = 50000,
            OnboardBags = 237,
            CheckedBags = 500,
        };
        textBoxMultiline.Text = o.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

Your question also states **I have a ListBox called `aircraftList`...**.

[image: show from listbox]

When a listbox is bound to `BindingList<AircraftDetails>` you can choose a property of your `AircraftDetails` class to show as the `DisplayMember` property.
Add code to the main form's `Load` event to set up the data source and the `ListBox`:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    .
    .
    .

    BindingList<AircraftDetails> Details = new BindingList<AircraftDetails>();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        aircraftDetails.DataSource = Details;
        aircraftDetails.DisplayMember = nameof(AircraftDetails.Flight);
        aircraftDetails.SelectedIndexChanged += onAircraftDetailsSelection;

        // Add a few flights
        Details.Add(new AircraftDetails
        {
            Flight = "UA6026",
            Airline = Airline.United,
            Fuel = 45250,
            OnboardBags = 155,
            CheckedBags = 97,
        });
        Details.Add(new AircraftDetails
        {
            Flight = "UA8888",
            Airline = Airline.United,
            Fuel = 27620,
            OnboardBags = 301,
            CheckedBags = 134,
        });
        Details.Add(new AircraftDetails
        {
            Flight = "WN8610",
            Airline = Airline.Southwest,
            Fuel = 200,
            OnboardBags = 5,
            CheckedBags = 614,
        });
        aircraftDetails.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

In response to selection changes, call this method to show object in textbox:

```
    private void onAircraftDetailsSelection(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(aircraftDetails.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            textBoxMultiline.Text = aircraftDetails.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/object-to-textbox.git) this sample

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. However, I still have some confusion on the topic. I am not adding aircrafts inside the code. I am using a form (`FlightSetup`) which will let the user add wherever they want about the aircraft and then display it just like you did! I got the idea, but I am still a little bit lost since you have a different way of showing details for each aircraft. I will provide my actual code just in case -> https://codeshare.io/dwRzwM (MAIN CODE) -- https://codeshare.io/OdPrdA (AIRCRAFTCLASS CODE)

Comment: I tried adding some of the code you provided, but I am still facing some errors. I am really sorry if this is annoying for you. I am still a beginner and I haven't see a lot of how data biding works :(

Comment: There's no need to apologize! Everyone giving answers here understands being in that place. Part of the fun is that there's _always_ some new coding challenge - to lose the feeling of being a "beginner" IMO would mean one isn't pushing hard enough. I do have a couple practical ideas for you in general.

Comment: First, there is different StackExchange site called [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) that is more geared to the kind of broad questions you're asking. StackOverflow deals mainly with narrow, focused questions. Make sure you have read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because it's a guide on how to get most helpful answers.

Comment: The other thing is for you to get a free GitHub account if you can. I think you'll find that there is a general reluctance to look at off-list code, but (on either site) if there is a GitHub project that can be easily cloned in Visual Studio it's a lot more likely someone will make the occasional exception.

Comment: Hey! So I tried asking the same question but adding the code so I can get more help on the topic. However, I would like to leave [my repository here](https://github.com/destrutoyt/UT-Aircrafts/tree/master)` just in case you can give me a hand :(

Comment: I created a new thread because I have an entirely different topic, but I was more interested in the response and code you supplied me because it works exactly how I want my code to function. I comprehended a great deal, however I am unable to add information from a submitted form to 'aircraftList' and 'detailsList'. Thank you for your support and I apologize for my rookie errors lol

Comment: That's great that you made the GitHub account and made a repo. This has made it easy for me to [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75040384/5438626).