# Items.Add cannot be used because it is not the "DataSource" C# + WindowsForm

Tags: c#, forms, oop

I am trying to add an item to `aircraftList` ListBox and be able to click on it and on a `detailsList` TextBox display all information per item selected. However, I am using `BindingList<AircraftDetails> Details = new BindingList<AircraftDetails>();` and `AircraftClass` which contains the following method:

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        List<string> builder = new List<string>();
        builder.add("something here like a variable");
```

which wil return all details to the `detailsList` textBox.

Now, the issue is that when I tried to do something like `aircraftList.Items.Add("Test")` it will show a error message showing this
[image]

I am at a loss for what to do, however I will provide the repository of my code that is hosted on gitHub so that you can better comprehend it. [REPOSITORY](https://github.com/destrutoyt/UT-Aircrafts/tree/master)

Comment: You shouldn't access the `ListBox.Items` collection when the control is bound to data source. Manipulate the data source itself to add/remove/edit the items. Also, your data source is `BindingList<AircraftDetails>`, so you should add new instances of the `AircraftDetails` model and not any other unrelated type like strings. i.e. `Details.Add("Test");` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for posting your repository in support of your question. That made it easy to reproduce the issue. Making a minor change to your `addaircraftButton_Click` "should" do the trick.

```
public void addaircraftButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FlightSetup addplane = new FlightSetup();
    AircraftDetails aircraftDetails = new AircraftDetails();
    using (addplane)
    {
        DialogResult result = addplane.ShowDialog();

        planeModel = addplane.planeModel_textbox.Text;
        airline = addplane.airline_textbox.Text;
        fuelG = double.Parse(addplane.fuel_textbox.Text);
        bag1 = int.Parse(addplane.carryonTextBox.Text);
        bag2 = int.Parse(addplane.checkedBagsTextBox.Text);

        object o = new AircraftDetails
        {
            AircraftModel = planeModel,
            Airline = airline,
            Fuel = fuelG, //TESTING
            OnBoardBags = bag1,
            CheckedBags = bag2,
            
            // Don't forget to assign TailNumber!
        };
        detailsList.Text = o.ToString();
    }

    //aircraftList.Items.Add(planeModel); // not working right here <--

    // Do this instead!
    Details.Add(aircraftDetails);
}
```

Obviously, you were very close to having the right code. The trick is that once you bind to a `DataSource`, you should work directly with that data `Details.Add(aircraftDetails)` and should no longer attempt to manipulate the UI control directly.

---

**Optimized Solution**

Consider that you could make `FlightSetup` responsible for creating a new `AircraftDetails`. If you remove all the event handlers that aren't doing anything, you get something like this:

```
public partial class FlightSetup : Form
{
    public FlightSetup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void buttonFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
    public AircraftDetails GetAircraftDetails()
    {
        var aircraftDetail = new AircraftDetails
        {
            // Please look into int.TryParse to make this more fault-tolerant.
            TailNumber = int.Parse(tailno_textbox.Text),
            AircraftModel = planeModel_textbox.Text,
            Airline = airline_textbox.Text,
            Fuel = double.Parse(fuel_textbox.Text),
            OnBoardBags = int.Parse(carryonTextBox.Text),
            CheckedBags = int.Parse(checkedBagsTextBox.Text),
        };
        return aircraftDetail;
    }
}
```

---

Now, back in the main form you have a squeaky-clean method:

```
public void addaircraftButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (FlightSetup addplane = new FlightSetup())
    {
        DialogResult result = addplane.ShowDialog();

        if(result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            AircraftDetails aircraftDetails = addplane.GetAircraftDetails();
            Details.Add(aircraftDetails);
            detailsList.Text = aircraftDetails.ToString();
            aircraftList.SelectedItem = aircraftDetails;
        }
    }
}
```

When your code is run after making these changes, here is the result:

[image: after adding]

Comment: THANK YOUUU! After almost three weeks, I am finally able to do that:DD!! THANK YOU A LOOOOOOTTTT :DDDDDDDDD!

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what the issue is. You cannot modify the Items collection when you have set the DataSource property. The whole point of binding a list to the control is that the control displays what's in that list. If you want to add a new item, you have to add it to the list you bound to the control.

Comment: Yes, I do know but I wasn't able to know how to solve it. Thank you thoughj :D!